# launch sms application from browser in Meteor

Tags: meteor

A Meteor client code running on smartphone needs to send SMS using the phone sms app. How would you approach this task with out EmailSMS gateway?

All the SO posts I read were not Meteor specific. Any one tried this [Cordova extensions](https://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html#App-accessRule) and can give some feedback on how to use it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cordova access rules you mention are only to handle special links that open the device's default app which handles the corresponding service.

Think of it exactly like a `<a href="mailto:recipient@email.com">Open a mail composer</a>` in a browser, that opens an email creation window from your default mail client when you click on the link. You can even pre-populate the body content of your SMS, like with the `mailto` link.

Now if I understand correctly your objective, you would like to automatically send an SMS, as if you had sent an email to an Email2SMS 3rd party service that would convert it to an SMS and send it to your recipient on your behalf. Except that you want to get rid of that 3rd party?

In that case, you would be interested in [actual Cordova plugins for SMS functionality](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=sms).